# 503 Return Code from Wildfly after HAProxy

Tags: java, load-balancing, wildfly-8, haproxy, http-status-code-503

I am doing load testing on setup LoadBalancer -> API Server (WildFly). Problem here is my api server stop responding and giving 503 through Load Blancer. While I have memory and cpu available at api server.

What could be possible reason that can happen ? I am thinking that i have to set max concurrent thread in wildfly to respond all requests ? Please suggest

-Usman

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this wildfly application, but 503 may be returned by HAProxy if no application servers are available in the farm.
Please enable logging in HAProxy and report here the log lines. Then I'll be able to tell you exactly what happens.

Baptiste

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes it's right that HAProxy is giving 503. I have tried to call api from the api server directly  to check the actual issue, it gives empty response. While CPU and Memory still available about 70%, so it seems to me that this is Wildfly that is creating problem. 

Wildfly console is accessible during that time when it is giving empty response over api call. What can be possible problems ?